# I need to insert the records in table as each row using javascript object?

Tags: javascript, php, object

My object having Day-wise slot details like from_time and to_time. I have to add each entry in a new row in the table. But array couldn't form using current receive object. My object follows:

```
    {
    Fri : (
    {
    "from_time" : "7:00 AM";
    "to_time" : "8:00 AM";
    },
    {
    "from_time" : "8:00 AM";
    "to_time" : "10:00 AM";
    },
    {
    "from_time" : "2:00 PM";
    "to_time" : "4:00 PM";
    }
    );
    Mon : (
    {
    "from_time" : "12:00 PM";
    "to_time" : "1:00 PM";
    },
    {
    "from_time" : "1:00 PM";
    "to_time" : "10:00 AM";
    },
    {
    "from_time" : "1:00 PM";
    "to_time" : "7:00 AM";
    }
    );
    Sat : (
    {
    "from_time" : "8:00 AM";
    "to_time" : "7:00 AM";
    },
    {
    "from_time" : "1:00 PM";
    "to_time" : "1:00 PM";
    },
    {
    "from_time" : "5:00 PM";
    "to_time" : "2:00 PM";
    }
    );
    Sun : (
    {
    "from_time" : "3:00 PM";
    "to_time" : "5:00 PM";
    },
    {
    "from_time" : "4:00 PM";
    "to_time" : "4:00 PM";
    },
    {
    "from_time" : "5:00 PM";
    "to_time" : "3:00 PM";
    }
    );
    Thu : (
    {
    "from_time" : "7:00 AM";
    "to_time" : "8:00 AM";
    },
    {
    "from_time" : "12:00 PM";
    "to_time" : "2:00 PM";
    },
    {
    "from_time" : "2:00 PM";
    "to_time" : "3:00 PM";
    }
    );
    Tue : (
    {
    "from_time" : "10:00 AM";
    "to_time" : "10:00 AM";
    },
    {
    "from_time" : "2:00 PM";
    "to_time" : "1:00 PM";
    },
    {
    "from_time" : "6:00 PM";
    "to_time" : "3:00 PM";
    }
    );
    Wed : (
    {
    "from_time" : "11:00 AM";
    "to_time" : "11:00 AM";
    },
    {
    "from_time" : "12:00 PM";
    "to_time" : "2:00 PM";
    },
    {
    "from_time" : "4:00 PM";
    "to_time" : "4:00 PM";
    }
    );
    }
```

Because I try many ways in php to get that object but object is not properly readable by code. To insert the records one by one using foreach.
I need to insert entry in table row like Fri 12:00 PM 04:00 PM.

Comment: Can you show what you tried ? So you need an array like `["Fri 07:00 AM 08:00AM", Fri 12:00 PM 04:00PM, ...]`?

Comment: What you are calling an "object" is not an object in any way.  Are you able to change how that is constructed?